# JdbcTemplate - Insert or update Oracle BLOB using SQL MERGE

Tags: spring, oracle, blob, jdbctemplate, sql-merge

Using JdbcTemplate I would like to call MERGE SQL statement which will insert a new record to the table or update if row with specific key already exists. The key part is that one of the column is of the Oracle BLOB type.

Here is what I tried till now:

Try 1.

Sql statement:

```
    String sql = ""
            + "MERGE INTO file_thumbnails "
            + "     USING (SELECT ? as file_c_id, ? as thumbnail_type, ? as thumbnail_image FROM DUAL) tmp "
            + "        ON (file_thumbnails.file_c_id = tmp.file_c_id AND "
            + "            file_thumbnails.thumbnail_type = tmp.thumbnail_type) "
            + "      WHEN MATCHED THEN "
            + "        UPDATE "
            + "           SET thumbnail_image = tmp.thumbnail_image "
            + "              ,thumbnail_date = SYSDATE "
            + "      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "
            + "        INSERT (c_id, file_c_id, thumbnail_type, thumbnail_image, thumbnail_date) "
            + "        VALUES (cedar_c_id_seq.nextval, tmp.file_c_id, tmp.thumbnail_type, tmp.thumbnail_image, SYSDATE)";
```

Database call:

```
List<Object[]> x = fileList.stream().map(file -> {
    byte[] thumbnail = file.getThumbnail();
    SqlLobValue sqlLobValue = new SqlLobValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(thumbnail), thumbnail.length, new DefaultLobHandler());
    return new Object[] { file.getFileCId(), file.getType().toString(), sqlLobValue};
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, x, new int[] { OracleTypes.NUMBER, OracleTypes.VARCHAR, OracleTypes.BLOB});
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [MERGE INTO file_thumbnails      USING (SELECT ? as file_c_id, ? as thumbnail_type, ? as thumbnail_image FROM DUAL) tmp         ON (file_thumbnails.file_c_id = tmp.file_c_id AND             file_thumbnails.thumbnail_type = tmp.thumbnail_type)       WHEN MATCHED THEN         UPDATE            SET thumbnail_image = tmp.thumbnail_image               ,thumbnail_date = SYSDATE       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN         INSERT (c_id, file_c_id, thumbnail_type, thumbnail_image, thumbnail_date)         VALUES (cedar_c_id_seq.nextval, tmp.file_c_id, tmp.thumbnail_type, tmp.thumbnail_image, SYSDATE)]; SQL state [72000]; error code [1461]; ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdate(BatchUpdateUtils.java:32) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:1000) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at cern.edms.thumbnails.generator.repository.EdmsFileRepository.saveThumbnails(EdmsFileRepository.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at cern.edms.thumbnails.generator.repository.EdmsFileRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e3d79386.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at cern.edms.thumbnails.generator.repository.EdmsFileRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70f43ba5.saveThumbnails(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at cern.edms.thumbnails.generator.Application.run(Application.java:58) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10401) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:966) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:950) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Try 2.

```
Sql statement:
        String sql = ""
                + "MERGE INTO file_thumbnails "
                + "     USING (SELECT ? as file_c_id, ? as thumbnail_type FROM DUAL) tmp "
                + "        ON (file_thumbnails.file_c_id = tmp.file_c_id AND "
                + "            file_thumbnails.thumbnail_type = tmp.thumbnail_type) "
                + "      WHEN MATCHED THEN "
                + "        UPDATE "
                + "           SET thumbnail_image = ? "
                + "              ,thumbnail_date = SYSDATE "
                + "      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "
                + "        INSERT (c_id, file_c_id, thumbnail_type, thumbnail_image, thumbnail_date) "
                + "        VALUES (cedar_c_id_seq.nextval, tmp.file_c_id, tmp.thumbnail_type, ?, SYSDATE)";
```

Database call:

```
List<Object[]> x = fileList.stream().map(file -> {
    byte[] thumbnail = file.getThumbnail();
    SqlLobValue sqlLobValue = new SqlLobValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(thumbnail), thumbnail.length, new DefaultLobHandler());
    SqlLobValue sqlLobValue2 = new SqlLobValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(thumbnail), thumbnail.length, new DefaultLobHandler());
    return new Object[] { file.getFileCId(), file.getType().toString(), sqlLobValue, sqlLobValue2 };
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, x, new int[] { OracleTypes.NUMBER, OracleTypes.VARCHAR, OracleTypes.BLOB, OracleTypes.BLOB });
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [MERGE INTO file_thumbnails      USING (SELECT ? as file_c_id, ? as thumbnail_type FROM DUAL) tmp         ON (file_thumbnails.file_c_id = tmp.file_c_id AND             file_thumbnails.thumbnail_type = tmp.thumbnail_type)       WHEN MATCHED THEN         UPDATE            SET thumbnail_image = ?               ,thumbnail_date = SYSDATE       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN         INSERT (c_id, file_c_id, thumbnail_type, thumbnail_image, thumbnail_date)         VALUES (cedar_c_id_seq.nextval, tmp.file_c_id, tmp.thumbnail_type, ?, SYSDATE)]; SQL state [63000]; error code [3106]; ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error
; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdate(BatchUpdateUtils.java:32) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:1000) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at cern.edms.thumbnails.generator.repository.EdmsFileRepository.saveThumbnails(EdmsFileRepository.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at cern.edms.thumbnails.generator.repository.EdmsFileRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e3d79386.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at cern.edms.thumbnails.generator.repository.EdmsFileRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$587b6598.saveThumbnails(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at cern.edms.thumbnails.generator.Application.run(Application.java:58) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10401) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:966) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:950) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Additional notes.

1. In the second try in the database call I cannot use twice the same `SqlLobValue` object because I am getting an exception:

   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate stream parameter: 4
2. If I will go with second try, but put the BLOB input parameter only once (for example only in the INSERT part of MERGE statement) it works correctly. But of course it doesn't solve my issue.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to @gvenzi answer, but decided to post my own answer as I have some additional comments.

So, yes, `OracleLobHandler` solves the problem. But in fact we are not forced to use deprecated class. In the [OracleLobHandler documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/OracleLobHandler.html) I found

> Deprecated.  in favor of DefaultLobHandler for the Oracle 10g driver
>   and higher. Consider using the 10g/11g driver even against an Oracle
>   9i database! DefaultLobHandler.setCreateTemporaryLob(boolean) is the
>   direct equivalent of this OracleLobHandler's implementation strategy,
>   just using standard JDBC 4.0 API. That said, in most cases, regular
>   DefaultLobHandler setup will work fine as well.

I tested it and it works.

But I had another problem using `SqlLobValue` together with `OracleTypes.BLOB` in `PreparedStatementSetter` (it is described here [ClassCastException: SqlLobValue cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BLOB using PreparedStatementSetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466988/classcastexception-sqllobvalue-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-sql-blob-using-prepared))

My final working code is as follow:

```
public void saveThumbnails(List<Thumbnail> fileList) throws SQLException, IOException {

    BatchPreparedStatementSetter b = new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
            Thumbnail thumbnail = fileList.get(i);
            byte[] thumbnailBytes = thumbnail.getThumbnail();
            ps.setObject(1, thumbnail.getFileCId(), OracleTypes.NUMBER);
            ps.setObject(2, thumbnail.getType().toString(), OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            DefaultLobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
            lobHandler.setCreateTemporaryLob(true);
            lobHandler.getLobCreator().setBlobAsBytes(ps, 3, thumbnailBytes);
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return fileList.size();
        }
    };
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(getSaveThumbnailSql(), b);
}

private String getSaveThumbnailSql() {
    // @formatter:off
    String sql = ""
            + "MERGE INTO file_thumbnails "
            + "     USING (SELECT ? as file_c_id, ? as thumbnail_type, ? AS thumbnail_image FROM DUAL) tmp "
            + "        ON (file_thumbnails.file_c_id = tmp.file_c_id AND "
            + "            file_thumbnails.thumbnail_type = tmp.thumbnail_type) "
            + "      WHEN MATCHED THEN "
            + "        UPDATE "
            + "           SET thumbnail_image = tmp.thumbnail_image"
            + "              ,thumbnail_date = SYSDATE "
            + "      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "
            + "        INSERT (c_id, file_c_id, thumbnail_type, thumbnail_image, thumbnail_date) "
            + "        VALUES (cedar_c_id_seq.nextval, tmp.file_c_id, tmp.thumbnail_type, tmp.thumbnail_image , SYSDATE)";
    //@formatter:on
    return sql;
}
```

Comment: thanks - the usage of the DefaultLobHandler solves the issue! I was already banging my head against the table! Is there an explanation why a "noraml" setObject/setBlob does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really a Spring framework expert but I could reproduce and somewhat debug your problem. It has to do with the `DefaultLobHandler` that you pass one which does seem to get bound as a `LONG` data type rather than a `BLOB` by error.

Here is a simplified test case of your above call with a batch size of one:

```
String sql = "MERGE INTO file_thumbnails "
        + "     USING (SELECT ? as file_c_id, ? as thumbnail_type, ? as thumbnail_image FROM DUAL) tmp "
        + "        ON (file_thumbnails.file_c_id = tmp.file_c_id AND "
        + "            file_thumbnails.thumbnail_type = tmp.thumbnail_type) "
        + "      WHEN MATCHED THEN "
        + "        UPDATE "
        + "           SET thumbnail_image = tmp.thumbnail_image "
        + "              ,thumbnail_date = SYSDATE "
        + "      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "
        + "        INSERT (file_c_id, thumbnail_type, thumbnail_image, thumbnail_date) "
        + "        VALUES (tmp.file_c_id, tmp.thumbnail_type, tmp.thumbnail_image, SYSDATE)";

byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/Users/gvenzl/Downloads/image1.JPG"));
ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
SqlLobValue sqlLobValue = new SqlLobValue(bin, content.length, new DefaultLobHandler());
List<Object []> x =  new ArrayList<Object []>();
x.add(new Object [] { 1, "Test", sqlLobValue});

jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, x, new int[] { OracleTypes.NUMBER, OracleTypes.VARCHAR, OracleTypes.BLOB});

System.out.print("Successful!");
```

I'm reading an image, then create a single item array and execute that the same way you have and error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [MERGE INTO file_thumbnails      USING (SELECT ? as file_c_id, ? as thumbnail_type, ? as thumbnail_image FROM DUAL) tmp         ON (file_thumbnails.file_c_id = tmp.file_c_id AND             file_thumbnails.thumbnail_type = tmp.thumbnail_type)       WHEN MATCHED THEN         UPDATE            SET thumbnail_image = tmp.thumbnail_image               ,thumbnail_date = SYSDATE       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN         INSERT (file_c_id, thumbnail_type, thumbnail_image, thumbnail_date)         VALUES (tmp.file_c_id, tmp.thumbnail_type, tmp.thumbnail_image, SYSDATE)]; SQL state [72000]; error code [1461]; ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

Now I'm changing the LOB handler from `DefaultLobHandler` to the deprecated `OracleLobHandler`:

```
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/Users/gvenzl/Downloads/image1.JPG"));
ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
SqlLobValue sqlLobValue = new SqlLobValue(bin, content.length, new OracleLobHandler());
List<Object []> x =  new ArrayList<Object []>();
x.add(new Object [] { 1, "Test", sqlLobValue});

jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, x, new int[] { OracleTypes.NUMBER, OracleTypes.VARCHAR, OracleTypes.BLOB});

System.out.print("Successful!");
```

And my out is:

```
Successful!
```

Debugging through it, the difference that I could see was that the `OracleLobHandler` uses the `ps.setBlob()` method while the `DefaultLobHandler` uses `ps.setBinaryStream()` which seems to result into the variable being bound as a `LONG` rather than a `BLOB`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It solves the issue, but please also check my answer with some additional comments.